# Why does do while() construct work properly in Chrome debugger but not in jsbin?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple code, without getting into full detail, I'll jump straight to brass tacks.

Here is the simple code snippet that has a do-while construct repeat until the input is not a NaN.

```js
do {
  var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
} while (isNaN(choice));
```

This code essentially prompts the user until a user's input meets while loop exit criteria. The code works fine if I execute in a chrome snippet. Although, the same code on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/) does not prompt even if I enter a string input. I am curious whether is it something with the code or the website?

Below is screenshot proof for the same:

<kbd>**Chrome Snippet**</kbd>

[image: Chrome Snippet execution]

<kbd>[jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com)</kbd>

[image: js-bin-execution]

Comment: Works here too...

Comment: add `// noprotect` at the top of the js file. Jsbin doesn't executes your code like you expect it to because it is trying to protect you from potential infinite loop.

Comment: yes i am. Just add the `// noprotect` comment at the top of your js code.

Comment: With your code and without the `// noprotect` comment, you will see a warning message in the browser dev tool console telling you to add the `// noprotect` comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does do-while not evaluate logical &&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235981/why-does-do-while-not-evaluate-logical)

Answer (score 1):

All thanks to @Yousaf, I was able to figure out and fix this issue on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/).

**Cause**

Absence of  `//noprotect`

**Fix**

Adding it on top of the code snippet of your [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/) code like below

```
//noprotect
--Your JS Code --
```

After a little searching, I was able to find it in their official documentation under the subsection : *Loop Protection*[here](https://jsbin.com/blog/protection/)