# Why does do-while not evaluate logical &&?

Tags: javascript

Here is a simple code snippet where I am ensuring the user input is a number and is between 1-3

```
do{
var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
}while(isNaN(choice) && (choice === 1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3));
```

While debugging I see the debugger does not even evaluate the part after `&&` where I am keeping a check on the input to be among 1, 2 or 3

Weirdly enough, the do-while construct works fine if I just have :

```
do{
var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
}while(isNaN(choice));
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: Problem is `isNaN` will always be true it not a `NAN` .It should be `!isNaN(choice) && (choice === 1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3));`

Comment: And PS: here are some useful hints for creating a RPS game: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65222824/383904 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904

Comment: @decpk Still doesnt work

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Appreciate it, I am more inclined in learning what i'm doing wrong here :)

Comment: @CamelCaseDev what doen't work

Comment: @decpk The prompt disappers even when i enter a wrong input like a string data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code looks now, you are looping as long as it's not a number *and* it's either 1, 2, or 3. Since those three are all valid numbers, the overall condition can never be true - if it's not a number then it won't be 1, 2 or 3, and if it's 1, 2 or 3 it won't be "not a number" (since it's a number).

From what you wrote, you want to keep looping if it's not a number *or* *not* one of those three:

```js
do {
  var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
} while (isNaN(choice) || !(choice === 1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3));
```

(I changed `&&` to `||` and added a `!` before the second part of the condition.)

However, since you are limiting it to three exact options anyway, you don't even need to check for NaN anymore, because as mentioned before, if it's 1, 2 or 3 it means it's not NaN anyway:

```js
do {
  var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
} while (!(choice === 1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3));
```

This becomes a bit easier to read by getting rid of the negation in the front, replacing `===` by `!==` and `||` by `&&`:

```js
do {
  var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
} while (choice !== 1 && choice !== 2 && choice !== 3);
```

An alternative way to simplify the previous code is to create an array with valid values and loop as long as this array doesn't include the actual input number:

```js
do {
  var choice = parseInt(prompt("Please select one of the following:\n1.ROCK\n2.PAPER\n3.SCISSORS\n[NOTE: Choose your selection by pressing a number between 1,2 or 3.]"));
} while (![1, 2, 3].includes(choice));
```

Comment: Wow, now I get what I was doing wrong exactly. I'll mark yours as an acceptable answer. Although others also helped me understand what I can do alternatively. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Assume that when you prompt a non-nan value e.g. a number, `isNaN` evaluates `false`, thereby going into [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554578/does-javascript-have-short-circuit-evaluation). However, I think you want to accept one of `1`,`2`, or `3` values. So shouldn't it be like `!(choice === 1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3)`? If one of them equals that value, no need to loop again.

Comment: So basically you're sugessting the do-while approach to validate the input is not the best way to approach this ?

Comment: @CamelCaseDev no, I don't mean such that. You eventually come up with using a loop mechanism to reach a validate input. (no mention recursion).

Comment: This is what i have in my while condtion based on what you said and the prompt disappears even on an invalid input `while(!isNaN(choice) && !(choice ===1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3))`

Comment: Just a gibberish string

Comment: @CamelCaseDev no need to check then against `isNan`

Comment: Yeah you're right, thanks to this amazing thread I learned it the reason why as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the first statement of the while loop is false the compiler doesnt compile the other statements after && here in this example `(choice === 1 || choice === 2 || choice === 3)` because it doesn`t matter what the other statements result is. The while loop is not executed at all.

This is compiler optimation (Short-circuit evaluation) for more information look at this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: Sure, i'll check out the article. Thank you you've helped me learn what i did wrong. Upvoting your answer

Answer (score 1):

A less complicated approach (avoiding `parseInt`, `isNaN` and multiple boolean checks) may be (snippet for the whole game ;):

[Play it here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scissorspaperrock?file=PlayFactory.js)

```js
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener( 'click', () => location.reload() );

let choices = ['ROCK', 'PAPER', 'SCISSORS']
let choice = 0;

while ( !choices[+choice-1] ) {
  choice = prompt(
    `1. ROCK; 2. PAPER; 3. SCISSORS`, `Enter 1, 2 or 3`);
}

const values = {
  yours: choices[choice-1], 
  mine: choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 )]};
const tie = values.yours === values.mine;
const iWin = values.yours === 'SCISSORS' && values.mine === 'ROCK' ||
  values.yours === 'ROCK' && values.mine === 'PAPER' ||
  values.yours === 'PAPER' && values.mine === 'SCISSORS';

console.log(`your choice: ${values.yours}, against: ${values.mine}. ${
  tie ? 'Tied...' : iWin ? 'You lost' : 'You win!'}` );
```

```html
<button>Again...</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's another novel approach which I'll consider using in my javascript code.